# Can Consume (combat drain) be used to dominate orcs?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

Provided you have selected Domination as the upgrade for the Drain skill, you can dominate orcs to fight for you by draining them. The Consume skill allows you to press A+B (on Xbox controllers) during combat to drain an enemy, provided your might is high enough.

Previously, I am sure I was able to dominate orcs during combat using the Consume skill. Now however, when I do so it kills the orc. Draining an enemy via the B button dominates them as normal, and the Domination upgrade is selected. Is there another skill upgrade that I have changed that is preventing combat dominations, or am I misremembering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that Domination is selected as the upgrade for Drain skill, the Consume skill *will* convert orcs by default. However, this behaviour may be changed by equipment.

In my particular case, a ring (named "Rune of Horrors") had as one of its bonuses:

> Consume attacks make enemy heads explode, causing nearby enemies to
>   flee

Removing this ring resulted in the regular Domination behaviour when using Consume.